# Apache process spawn without loging to access.log

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, memory, process

**Problem:** Apache processes were spawned without logging any activity to access.log.

`mysld` was killed because server ran out of memory (running on physical only, no swap for now). Checked the `syslog`, searched for events at that exact moment. It started with

```
localhost kernel: [5913722.705565] apache2 invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
```

Then some lines I consider not relevant here, followed by tons (~150 in one second, normally no more than 10) of

```
localhost kernel: [5913722.706310] [30772]    33 30772    98583     6989     132        0             0 apache2
```

And finally

```
Out of memory: Kill process 320 (mysqld) score 228 or sacrifice child
Killed process 320 (mysqld) total-vm:904928kB, anon-rss:113960kB, file-rss:0kB
```

AFAIK, they are all `apache2` processes and they are spawned (mostly) to handle requests. If so, the requests should be logged in `access.log`. That does not happen in my case.

**Question:** what could be the reason for `apache2` spawning so many of them? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably configured Apache to use far more than all of your ram. This is a common mistake.

httpd processes are nothing to do with MySQL processes.

httpd processes are spawned up to a certain point, but primarily to serve end user requests - more end user requests = more httpd spawned, up to the limit set in configuration, which appears to be 256 (for instance). That means it's going to make 256 children.

I am assuming you are using a Prefork Apache, and an in-process application server (such as PHP or mod_perl). In this model, you will end up with a maximum of (MaxClients * max memory usage of your application per process) memory used. If you don't have nearly that much, it's time to decrease one, the other or both.

In the general case, this means decreasing MaxClients to the point where your server has enough ram to cope.

Comment: httpd processes are handled by apache. More requests = more processes = more memory used = less memory available = possibility for mysql to die.

Comment: See the question. Why apache is spawning so many of them out of thin air (at least so far...)?